# Unable to update database column - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am trying to update a column in a table by using this function:

```
-(void)updateID:(NSString*)ID{
    NSString *queryInsertAndUpdate =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"UPDATE mytable set ID = '%@' limit 1",ID];

    const char* query=[queryInsertAndUpdate UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nil;

    sqlite3_exec(_database, "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Query Executed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Query NOT Executed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    }else{
        NSLog(@"Statement NOT Prepared: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
    }
}
```

When I run this function everything works fine and the column gets updated. I know that because I make a call to the database about the specific table and I check the results. The thing is, when I call the same function that reads the entries of the table from another class, I get different results.

Specifically, when I call:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate initViewController];
```

inside `initViewController` I call the same function that reads the table and I get the entry of the column before the update.

Why is this happening? I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: You're updating a random row in the table, is this really intended? Shouldn't the sql query contain a `WHERE ...` clause? Also, I hope the `ID` column isn't a primary key.

Comment: The table has only one row, so it's not a random row

Comment: Well the `limit 1` fooled me. I am not an expert on the sqlite3 library you're using but if you call _"BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION"_, shouldn't you also have a _COMMIT TRANSACTION_?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. You can write it as an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION", then you also need to have a COMMIT TRANSACTION